# Convert rows to column using CASE in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, case

I have a table like this:

| ipiresia | program |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I want to make a query to transform the table like this:

| ipiresia | program1 | program2 | program3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | x | x |
| 2 | x | x | x |
| 3 | x | x | x |
| 4 | x | x |  |

I have used this query but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT ipiresia, (CASE program WHEN '1' THEN 'x' ELSE NULL) AS program1, (CASE   program WHEN '2' THEN 'x' ELSE NULL) AS program2, (CASE program WHEN '3' THEN 'x' ELSE NULL) AS program3 FROM table GROUP BY ipiresia
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: I think my case is different than the one you point out.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to explain why

Comment: Because in the example you gave there are three columns and the CASE is based on the 3rd column. I don't know if this is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems sufficiently similar to me, but anyway...

```
SELECT ipiresia
     , MAX(CASE WHEN program = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END) program1 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN program = 2 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END) program2 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN program = 3 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END) program3 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY ipiresia;
```

Personally, I wouldn't do this - preferring where possible to handle issues of data display in application-level code.